# PHP exec code not working

Tags: php, html

Im trying to run this code, it works so code so far till the code tries to execute a function to create a pic from a temp file. here it is not working well:

```
    // create temporary latex file
    $fp = fopen($this->_tmp_dir."/".$this->_tmp_filename.".tex","a+");
    fputs($fp,$latex_document);
    fclose($fp);

    // create temporary dvi file
    $command = $this->_latex_path." --interaction=nonstopmode ".$this->_tmp_filename.".tex";
    $status_code = exec($command);

    if (!$status_code) { $this->cleanTemporaryDirectory(); chdir($current_dir); $this->_errorcode = 4; return false; }

    // convert dvi file to postscript using dvips
    $command = $this->_dvips_path." -E ".$this->_tmp_filename.".dvi"." -o ".$this->_tmp_filename.".ps";
    $status_code = exec($command);

    // imagemagick convert ps to image and trim picture
    $command = $this->_convert_path." -density ".$this->_formula_density.
                " -trim -transparent \"#FFFFFF\" ".$this->_tmp_dir."/".$this->_tmp_filename.".ps ".
                $this->_tmp_dir."/".$this->_tmp_filename.".".$this->_image_format;      
    $status_code = exec($command);

    $latexlog = fopen($this->_tmp_dir."/latex.log","a+");
    fputs($latexlog,$command);
    fclose($latexlog);

    // test picture for correct dimensions
   $dim = $this->getDimensions($this->_tmp_filename.".".$this->_image_format);


    if ( ($dim["x"] > $this->_xsize_limit) or ($dim["y"] > $this->_ysize_limit)) {
       $this->cleanTemporaryDirectory();
        chdir($current_dir);
        $this->_errorcode = 5;
        $this->_errorextra = ": " . $dim["x"] . "x" . number_format($dim["y"],0,"","");
        return false;
    }

    // copy temporary formula file to cahed formula directory
    $latex_hash = md5($latex_formula . ";fd=" . $this->_formula_density);
    $filename = $this->getPicturePath()."/".$latex_hash.".".$this->_image_format;



    $latexlog = fopen($this->_tmp_dir."/latex1.log","a+");
    fputs($latexlog,$filename);
    fclose($latexlog);



$status_code = copy($this->_tmp_filename.".".$this->_image_format,$filename);
```

and th content of the latex1.log is :

```
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tiki/lib/equation/pictures/35d8c95bf51a397b06a20078c95f8ff4.png"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tiki/lib/equation/pictures/35d8c95bf51a397b06a20078c95f8ff4.png"
```

and the latex.log:

```
   "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/convert.exe" -density 120 -trim -transparent "#FFFFFF" C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tiki/lib/equation/tmp/e940a3ba6df738388b772344a8a112e4.ps C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tiki/lib/equation/tmp/e940a3ba6df738388b772344a8a112e4.png"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/convert.exe" -density 120 -trim -transparent "#FFFFFF" C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tiki/lib/equation/tmp/8671e7b4d35f3d498f22e225dbe70bd9.ps C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tiki/lib/equation/tmp/8671e7b4d35f3d498f22e225dbe70bd9.png
```

beside this error in the html :

```
PHP (5.6.30) ERROR (E_WARNING):
File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tiki\lib\equation\class.latexrender.php
Line: 284
Type: copy(8671e7b4d35f3d498f22e225dbe70bd9.png): failed to open stream: No     such file or directory
```

Comment: Well, the last message you posted is pretty clear. Apparently whatever logic is throwing that fails to open that file. Most likely an issue with path and position in the file system.

Comment: try `shell_exec` instead of `exec`. Get an output with [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)'s 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using code intended for execution on a Linux system in Windows. I'm guessing this because the path to the image mixes `/` with `\`:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tiki/lib/equation/pictures/35d8c95bf51a397b06a20078c95f8ff4.png"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tiki/lib/equation/pictures/35d8c95bf51a397b06a20078c95f8ff4.png"
```

You could try using `\`, or maybe the PHP constant, `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. It might help your debugging if you added checks along the way that all [files exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) before doing anything with them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "copying to cmd"

Comment: i mean just run this code in cmd, it generates the pic